# Discord.js when I kick a person I want to see it in a channel + as a embed msg

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed, discord.js

I'm using discord.js: "discord.js": "12.1.1" and this script is already looking OK.
So I made command handler and in that command folder I made a file called 'kickuser.js'

The permission is good, the kick is working as inteded.
But Now I want this to be also send to a specific channel + as a embed.

Person who did the kicking:
Action: Kick/Ban    || this is for later
Reason: reason...

When he was kicked * yesterday at 13:46

```
var kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Kick")
    .setColor("#ee0000")
    .addField("Kicked by", message.author);
  //.addField("Kicked user", ?)
 //.setFooter("time ?")
```

Below you can see my script 'kickuser.js'

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) =>{

    if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {

      if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
          return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');
      }

      else {

          let member = message.mentions.members.first();
          let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(' ');

          if(member.kickable == false) {
              message.channel.send("That user cannot be kicked!");
              return;
          }

          else {


              if(reason == ``) {
                  reason = (`No reason provided.`)
              }


              await member.send(`You have been kicked from **${message.guild.name}** with the reason: **${reason}**`)
              .catch(err => message.channel.send(`⚠ Unable to contact **${member}**.`));

              await member.kick(reason)
              await message.channel.send(` ${member} Reason: ${reason}`);

              console.log(`${message.author.tag} kicked ${member.user.tag} from '${message.guild.name}' with the reason: '${reason}'.`);

            }


      }

  }

      else {
      message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use kick.");
      return;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit to make it cleaner and I also wrote the embed for you.

You had to get the channel by accessing the guild's channels and looking for the ID of the channel you want to log the kick in using `message.guild.channels.cache.get()` then sending the embed you've created by using `.send(embed)` like you send any other message.

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {

        if (!message.mentions.users) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');

        else {

            const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID_HERE);
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(' ');

            if (member.kickable == false) return message.channel.send("That user cannot be kicked!");

            else {

                if (!reason) reason = (`No reason provided.`);

                await member.send(`You have been kicked from **${message.guild.name}** with the reason: **${reason}**`)
                    .catch(err => message.channel.send(`⚠ Unable to contact **${member}**.`));

                await member.kick(reason);

                const kickEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.avatarURL())
                    .setColor("#ee0000")
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .addField("Kicked By", message.author.tag)
                    .addField("Reason", reason);

                await channel.send(kickEmbed);

                console.log(`${message.author.tag} kicked ${member.user.tag} from '${message.guild.name}' with the reason: '${reason}'.`);

            }
        }
    } else {
        message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use kick.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to post all my errors that I have right now: 
1 -> (node:19984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Discord is not defined         // possible solution go to kickusers.js go to line 1 and change
const discord to const Discord

|| the second error -> So when I fixed error 1, I don't know if it's the right solution.
Then I get this error:
 (node:16084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: member.user.iconURL is not a function

You can find my pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/zFUJTsYJ

Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Sorry about that, I had 2 mistakes in my answer, I have fixed those mistakes, go ahead and copy the whole code block and test it.

Comment: First of all thank you, for your time. The next error I run into is:
(node:21180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: Did you pass the Channel ID in `const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID_HERE);`? If so, did you pass it as a string or a number? it needs to be a string.

If you did pass a string, are you sure you copied the right ID?

Comment: Nice! 
Yeah I forgot to paste it as a string... silly me. The last thing that is missing, is the avatar of the user that has been kicked. This is how it looks right now: https://ibb.co/6ybkCRX

Comment: Does the user have a default avatar? if not, console.log(member.user.avatarURL())

Comment: Can I show this just a bit bigger?
Now it's really small. I think it's because it's on the same line of code.
But I tried to put it on another line, but it doesn't work.. or I just get the url.Here you can find a preview of how it looks now. 
https://ibb.co/x6Qb1SL

Comment: So it works as intended now, right? Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: I just was looking to get it bigger, like the new print screen.
https://ibb.co/Nx8N5BR I think that's better, because the previous avatar is to small.

Comment: You can do that with `.setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())`

Comment: Really thanks for all the updates/comments.
Thanks!